# Flutter: Better way to use ObjectKeys?

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am using a StatefulWidget whose constructor contains an Object, like

```
class X extends StatefulWidget {
  X({this.o});
  Object o;
...
}
```

As it sometimes happens, this object `o` changes, but the widget `X` does not update, so I had to add an ObjectKey in the constructor:

```
class X extends StatefulWidget {
  X({this.o, this.key});
  Object o;
  ObjectKey key;
...
}
```

Now every time I call the constructor, I have to call `X(o: o, key: ObjectKey(o));`. Is there a better way of doing this? It would be nice, if the constructor itself manages that, like

```
class X extends StatefulWidget {
  X({this.o, this.key = ObjectKey(o)});
  Object o;
  ObjectKey key;
...
}
```

But as `ObjectKey(o)` is not a constant expression, it cannot be used as a default parameter. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by using this notation in your constructor:

```dart
class X extends StatefulWidget {
  X({this.o}) : key = ObjectKey(o);
  Object o;
  ObjectKey key;
}
```

This is called the *initializer list*, which you can find more about [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list).